# Why is this jQuery ajax failing?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do some really basic AJAX using PHP & jQuery, but for some reason when I enter text into the input field and click the button I'm always getting null data back. What am I doing wrong?

WebService.php:

```
<?php
    $return['ReturnString'] = $_POST['SearchString'];
    for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++)
    {
        $return['ReturnString'] = $return['ReturnString'] . $_POST['SearchString'];
    }
    return json_encode($return);
?>
```

HTML:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("jquery", "1");
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/script.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="txtJavaPHP" />
                <input type="button" id="btnJavaPHP" value="Go" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <span id="spanJavaPHP"></span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Script.js:

```
$(document).ready(SetupButtonClicks);
function SetupButtonClicks() {$('#btnJavaPHP').click(DoPHP);}

    function DoPHP() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: 'WebService.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            SearchString: $('#txtJavaPHP').val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == null)
                $('#spanJavaPHP').text("Data is null");
            else
                $('#spanJavaPHP').text(data.ReturnString);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#spanJavaPHP').text('There was an error: ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you using FireBug? Look at the request response and start from there.

Comment: That's the thing I'm not getting any response. Its really wierd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem lies here, but I have not used AJAX for a while, so I was not able to fully go through the AJAX Code:

```
echo $return['ReturnString'];
return json_encode($return);
```

You should be echoing the `json_encode($return);`

`echo json_encode($return);`

This should hopefully fix it. Although I do not know why you are looping that data 100 times...but yea.

Comment: This fixed it. I'm looping the data 100 times just do create a larger payload and to just have something to send for this test.